# replace apache and mod_weblogic with nginx and what?

Tags: nginx, weblogic, wildfly

I have a two nodes WebLogic (and a positively ancient version of WebLogic to boot) cluster that I plan to retire where WebLogic will be replaced by WildFly and Apache with Nginx. The problem I am facing right now is how to replace `mod_weblogic` from the Apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicHost 192.168.0.1
    WebLogicPort 7003
</IfModule>
<LocationMatch "/services/.*/(buy|sell|status)">
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicCluster 192.168.0.1:7003,192.168.0.2:7003
    PathTrim /services
    PathPrepend /requestprocessor
    WLIOTimeoutSecs 600
</LocationMatch>
```

In this example, from what I understand, provides `mod_weblogic` load balancing between the two nodes, right? I have to admit that I have no idea how this module works, only that I am about to replace it… :-)

How can I achieve the same result with Nginx and WildFly?

I found a guide on the Nginx website about load balancing ( https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/jboss-load-balancing-nginx-plus/) and I guess the big question is if there is anything in the functionality of `mod_weblogic` that I am missing or if doing as the guide suggests will provide the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do load balancing with a lot of tools now. for example haproxy
http://biemond.blogspot.com/2010/04/high-availability-load-balancer-for.html

or nginx https://www.nginx.com/blog/load-balance-oracle-weblogic-server/

or apache https://theheat.dk/blog/?p=916

or varnish https://varnish-cache.org/

they all have similar abilities. as far as I know, now mod_weblogic does not have any specialty other then nginx or varnish or haproxy. apache proxy module can be hard to configure but still does the job.

long time ago there was no nginx or varnish there people start using mod_weblogic. it was a default product for weblogic. now we have all other options. you just need to test and fine-tune your choice.

Comment: The weblogic plugin communicates with the weblogic server cluster where it sends requests. Therefor, if any member leaves or joins the cluster, the plugin will be informed very quickly and will be able to include or exclude the member for the load balancing. In this situation other products like HAproxy will rely on a timeout to detect that a server left the cluster and to stop sending requests to it.